# Is there any reason to use another function to validate user input on a login screen whent he login screen is on the main page?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

As I have right now, I have 3 functions: Main,Login and Panel. Explanation of the 3 functions:

**Main**

This is the home page. The thing is, on this page there is a login screen as well. So the input will be sent to the function 'Login'.

**Login**

This is where (only) all the validation will be. If validation fails, I'm sending it back to the Main with the error messages, and if it succeeds, It'll go further to the function 'Panel'.

**Panel**

Success. You logged in. Nothing special here.

---

Now my problem is, everything described in the function **Login**, can mostly fit in the **Main** function. Is there any reason to not just get everything from **Login** and put it in **Main**? So basically when the form is sent, if it fails, stay on the same page but with error messages or 'Succes! you logged in.' I feel like I'm overthinking this too much.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no repetition, validation must be separate function for example validateData(Login) and similar (in calcFunctions.php) 
HTML functions should be also in separate functions in for example (view)showFunctions.php then you proceed procedural in index.php you start with if session does not exists you do this else that.
Function login, main and similar are bad because I don't know what they are doing just by looking at their names. Functions you can use for example for particular actions in index.php. showInfoForEveryone, showInfoForLoggedIn, showSingupAndLogin, cleanData, showFormSingUP, showFormSingIn, errortable (array for errors that you can display if there is any), validateData() etc..
This way there is no repetition.